# How to escape ] char in character class in sed

Tags: sed, escaping, substitution

`echo "eh]" | sed -r 's/[\]a]/lol/g'` returns `eh]` instead of `ehlol`. no errors are raised so I assume `\]` is some kind of sed magic. Im tired of constant sed problems, but I have to use it. so how to escape ] in sed substition expression?

Comment: Use `echo "eh]" | sed -r 's/[]a]/lol/g'` (without the backslash). See the explanation about `\` not special inside `[` `]` in the sed info documentation in the chapter `Regular Expressions`

Comment: thanks, but it seems to work only when `]` is the first char in character class. E.g. `[a]b]` deosn't work. I would highly prefer not being forced to do that. Any other solutions?

Comment: @nah Yes it must be at the first position. Read the manual. ;)

Comment: Please read up the mentioned documentation. It clearly states that `]` has to be the first char in the character class in order to be not considered end  of class.

Comment: Ok I couldn't ctrl+f that 'not special inside', but I found: `']'
     ends the bracket expression if it's not the first list item.  So,
     if you want to make the ']' character a list item, you must put it
     first.`. This just made me hate sed even more. Anyway please put your comment as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: @nah that's to do with regular expression, not specific to sed.. the same constraint applies to grep, awk, perl, etc

Comment: @Sundeep any other regex engine I know allows me to escape it at any position: https://regex101.com/r/XpnUxA/1

Comment: ok, checked again... awk, perl also allows escaping at any position... grep doesn't, unless you use pcre regex with `-P`

Comment: Any tool that allows escaping `]` within a bracket expression is implementing a private, non-POSIX extension. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) clearly states `The right-bracket ( ']' ) shall lose its special meaning and represent itself in a bracket expression if it occurs first in the list (after an initial circumflex ( '^' ), if any). Otherwise, it shall terminate the bracket expression`. So if you use that `\]` notation just don't rely on it being portable to other tools/versions. Best to simply put the `]` first.

Comment: If you want to use modern (extended) regexes in sed, you can (probably) use `sed -E` (`-E` is not portable sed, but you are using the non-portable `-r` so you probably are okay with that).  Note that your complaints about backslashes have nothing to do with sed and everything to do with using basic regular expressions instead of extended regular expressions.

Comment: To replace `]` in sed, you can just do `sed 's/]/lol/g'.  You should probably change the title to reflect the character class.

Comment: Done. It might be true that sed is not an exception, but coming from python I refuse to learn more about basic regexes just because university requires me to use pre-columbian tools. Grep has -P option, sed does not (-E doesn't work for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `echo "eh]" | sed -r 's/[]a]/lol/g'`:

- without the backslash
- and `]` as first character inside the brackets.

`]` and `\` have some specialties when used inside brackets.
Let me cite from the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html):

> A leading ^ reverses the meaning of list, so that it matches any single character not in list. **To include ] in the list, make it the first character** (after the ^ if needed), to include - in the list, make it the first or last; to include ^ put it after the first character.
>
> The characters `$, *, ., [,` and `\` are normally **not special** within list. For example, `[\*]` matches either ‘\’ or ‘*’, because the \ is not special here. However, strings like [.ch.], [=a=], and [:space:] are special within list and represent collating symbols, equivalence classes, and character classes, respectively, and [ is therefore special within list when it is followed by ., =, or :. Also, when not in POSIXLY_CORRECT mode, special escapes like \n and \t are recognized within list. See Escapes.

Comment: wrt `character class brackets` - you're mixing 2 terms. This discussion is about bracket expressions, not character classes. You can use a character class inside a bracket expression but they're 2 separate things. A character class would be `[:alpha:]`, a bracket expression that includes a character class would be `[[:alpha:]]` and a bracket expression that includes a locale-dependent similar character range instead of a character class would be `[a-zA-Z]`.